# Pass event to parent view?

Tags: java, android

I have a layout which contains five TextView. When user clicks any of the five TextView, it will do the same thing: open another activity. So, the OnClickerListener behavior to the five TextView is the same.
Is it possible that I only add OnClickListerner to one view, e.g. to layout, so I don't have to add OnClickListerner to each of the five TextView?
Put it another way, if none of the children components receives CLICK event, will the CLICK event passed through to their parent, the layout?

Thanks.

Comment: You can add an OnClickerListener to almost any view as far as I know.

Answer (score 7):

The above answer from Mayra is not correct.  If the lowest level control (i.e. textview in your case) does **not** have an OnClickListener() associated with it, then the click event  "bubble up" to the parent.  It will continue this way until a view is found that implements an OnClickListener; otherwise the click is ignored (I assume).  I have taken advantage of this behavior many times.

Also, refer to this post for more details:  [Stackoverflow Question 8135032](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135032/does-making-parent-clickable-makes-all-child-element-clickable-as-well)

I know this is a very old post, but wanted to correct it for anyone else that stumbles upon this question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is another place to automatically receive click inputs from all views in a layout.

You could extend TextView with your custom OnClick behavior.

Or, just pass the same OnClickListener instance to all of your text boxes.

Comment: This behavior is incorrect.  See my answer.  The events bubble up.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the case but I recently spent a couple of hours trying to make a TextView propagate its click events to its parent. I wasn't being successful because apparently if you set the MovementMethod 
`tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`
it will catch the "bubbling-up" and never reach its parent.