# How to pass a view's onClick event to its parent on Android?

Tags: android, events, onclick, textview

I have a TextView in a layout whos background is a Selector. And the TextView's text is set to Spanned from HTML.
Then I set the TextView with the LinkMovementMethod.

Now when I tap on the TextView, the click event is not sent to its parent layout to trigger the selector.

How should this be solved?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I think you need to use one of those methods in order to be able to intercept the event before it gets sent to the appropriate components:

`Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` - This allows your Activity to intercept all touch events before they are dispatched to the window.

`ViewGroup.onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` - This allows a ViewGroup to watch events as they are dispatched to child Views.

`ViewParent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean)` - Call this upon a parent View to indicate that it should not intercept touch events with onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent).

More information [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html#EventHandlers).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is there an easier way to pass the events to trigger the onClick and onLongClick in parent view, or I have to implement them myself?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136696/pass-event-to-parent-view
Possibly you might want to try passing the same click listener to the other instances as suggested, even though I don't know if it will work, but might be worth a try.

Comment: Answer below is much cleaner

Comment: Should I instantiate the MotionEvent? Please, explain, @LuisMiguelSerrano

Comment: @olegario, typically you redefine the method for example for dispatchTouchEvent, with @Override, to define a new behavior for it, so you just receive a motion event the system has provided to your activity (or another component of your application), and you treat it and/or forward to any number of children components according to your own rules.
Something like:

`@Override public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) { ... }`

Answer (score 248):

Declare your `TextView` not clickable / focusable by using `android:clickable="false"` and `android:focusable="false"` or `v.setClickable(false)` and `v.setFocusable(false)`. The click events should be dispatched to the `TextView`'s parent now.

**Note:**

*In order to achieve this*, you have to add click to its direct `parent`. or set 
`android:clickable="false"` and `android:focusable="false"` to its direct parent **to pass listener to further parent**.

Comment: Oh man if I could give this +100 I would.  Been trying to figure out how to make a click only work in a ViewPager and not in the adapters layout with TouchImageView implementing onTouch!  This solution worked like a charm.

Comment: Works perfectly. Much better than the excepted answer.

Comment: but what if I want to handle Focus change event of EditText ?

Comment: @SweetWisherヅ: please provide some source code and explain your problem in detail. In general, dispatching events from views might also work, but I cannot help you unless you provide more useful information.

Comment: The scenario is : I have a layout which contains edittext ,relative layout,  spinner and list view. I want to fire touch event of parent layout whenever i touch on anywhere on the screenexcept the edittext and spinner

Comment: Why wonT this work for a ListView instead of a TextView? anyone?

Comment: Something important to bear in mind is that if you use `TextView#setOnClickListener()` on the `TextView`, it becomes clickable, even if it's declared as `android:clickable="false"`, and even if the the `ClickListener` is set to `null` (`setOnclickListener(null)`)

Comment: But this solution is making the imageView unclickable, and thus only clicking outside the image is triggering the click.

Comment: What if I want both the parent and the child to intercepte their OnClick ?

Comment: I want to pass the onclick event to the parent but I Don't need to pass this event while Onlong press. what is the best solution. your solution is best for only onclick event

Comment: @Tarikhelian: I would suggest using RecyclerView now, it allows you to be more flexible in this regard. Basically you would first declare all child views clickable=false and focusable=false and set a OnLongClickListener / OnClickListener on the parent view. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Nepster: I don't get what you are trying to say with your edit, are you talking about dispatching a click event to a parent view further up the hierarchy (referring to: "add click")? Please clarify. I hope you don't mind me correcting some of the grammatical errors ;).

Comment: I have experience that if we set clickable and focusable = false to any View. It retrun false to handle the event. So the event pass to it's parent . And if that parent also don't want to handle the event . they should also set Focusable and clickable = false.

Comment: Fun fact: if in TextView there is an `android:inputType` attribute it will silently consume click events even with clickable: false & focusable: false; in my case it was set in a style and it cost me 30 minutes to figure out the cause.

Comment: Just disabling `clickable` wasn't enough for me, I had to disable `focusable` as well in addition to `android:duplicateParentState="true"` https://stackoverflow.com/a/10171233/904344

Answer (score 25):

Sometime only this helps:

```
View child = parent.findViewById(R.id.btnMoreText);
    child.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View parent = (View) v.getParent();
            parent.performClick();
        }
    });
```

Another variant, works not always:

```
child.setOnClickListener(null);
```

Comment: This worked for `CardView` as the child view, since `CardView` seems to ignore `clickable="false"` and `focusable="false"`.  However, using `setOnTouchListener` and calling `onTouchEvent` on the parent instead allows the parent to display touch feedback (e.g. ripple effect).

Comment: I posted relevant code below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52928884/5652513.

Answer (score 16):

Put

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
```

in child then the views get its drawable state (focused, pressed, etc.) from its direct parent rather than from itself.
you can set onclick for parent and it call on child clicked

Comment: OP wants to call parent's click listener when child is clicked, not wise versa.

Answer (score 7):

If your `TextView` create click issues, than remove `android:inputType=""` from your xml file.

Comment: If you don't know why, I recommend you don't do it.  Just saying...to each his own.

Comment: You should set it to ```android:inputType="none"```

Comment: I had same issue. In textview I have set `android:inputType="textCapWords"`

Answer (score 5):

This answer is similar to [Alexander Ukhov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30365573/5652513), except that it uses touch events rather than click events.  Those event allow the parent to display the proper pressed states (e.g., ripple effect).  This answer is also in Kotlin instead of Java.

```
view.setOnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
    (view.parent as View).onTouchEvent(motionEvent)
}
```

Comment: Helpful answer, thanks! But I would suggest the following clarifications: 1) use other name for touched view - 'touchedView', for example; 2) call performClick() instead of onTouchEvent()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to both `OnTouch` and `OnClick` listener to parent and child view both, please use below trick:

1. User ScrollView as a Parent view and inside that placed your child view inside Relative/LinearLayout.
2. Make Parent ScrollView `android:fillViewport="true"` so View not be scrolled.
3. Then set `OnTouch` listener to parent and `OnClick` listener to Child views.
   And enjoy both listener callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

> Then I set the TextView with the LinkMovementMethod.

`TextView.setMovementMethod()` internally calls a private method `fixFocusableAndClickableSettings`. It is the root of the problem: calls `setFocusable(FOCUSABLE); setClickable(true); setLongClickable(true);`. So no matter what clickability you think you've set, it'll be all true.

[source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java)

Those 3 flags have to be reset back to false in order for the view to become non-clickable.