# ListView with two buttons

Tags: android

I am trying to make a listView with two buttons on each row. I have an adapter where the buttons and the rest views of my list are declared. My problem is that I can not fire the buttons from my main activity. I thought the code below should work but it didn't.

```
  public class Zmenu extends Activity {

   final EfficientAdapter Myadapter=new EfficientAdapter(this);

    final ListView l1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

    l1.setAdapter(Myadapter);

    l1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                            long arg3) {
                    switch(arg1.getId()) {
            case R.id.Button1 :
                    //do this block
                break;
        case R.id.Button2 :
                   //do this block
                break;
        }
}});
}
```

Can anyone helps me on what I am doing wrong in how could I fire the key listener in my main activity?

Comment: try by adding the button's action listener in the getView() of the adapter.

Comment: Wait... But where is the `setContentView(R.layout.my_list);`?

Comment: Ii havent invole the whole code here just what I think is important.
It works adding the listener in the getView of the adapter but I wqas wondering how I could do this from my main activity.

Answer (score 1):

Either you will need to let the events from the button percolate to the parent listview (see [How to pass the onClick event to its parent on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415528/how-to-pass-the-onclick-event-to-its-parent-on-android)) or in your `EfficientAdapter`'s `getView()` function, you need to register the listener with each button in the item.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  you don't have the correct code layout.  You need to implement your code in an onCreate function

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);//here goes your layout

        final EfficientAdapter Myadapter=new EfficientAdapter(this);

        final ListView l1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

        l1.setAdapter(Myadapter);

        l1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                switch(arg1.getId()) {
                        case R.id.Button1 :
                            //do this block
                            break;
                        case R.id.Button2 :
                            //do this block
                            break;
                    }
                }
          });
 }
```

Comment: Yes I have already do this the point is if the "setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()" should work or and how can I fire an on key listener from my main activity