# android make View transparent to input

Tags: android, input, android-view

I have a `RelativeLayout` with a thin red frame background and a (mostly transparent) `ImageView` as a child. Their sizes are equal:

[image]

On screen it looks as follows:

[image]

When user presses this compound object, I want to change frame's color to green:

[image]

I set `RelativeLayout`'s background to a `StateListDrawable` that switches red to green. It works fine until I add a child `ImageView` (representing blue letter "A") to the `RelativeLayout`. This ImageView intercepts input touches and therefeore blocks input. I tried to call

```
imageView.setEnabled(false);
imageView.setFocusable(false);
relativeLayout.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS);
```

but nothing helped.

How do I make an ImageView "transparent" to input events?

Comment: Easiest way: set an OnClickListener to your View and in onCLick() toggle the color change.

Comment: @Nick http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415528/how-to-pass-the-onclick-event-to-its-parent-on-android might be helpful to you. Nicely done question by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Set an OnTouchListener to the ImageView that returns false in any case. This way the touch  event wont be consumed and gets passed on to the next Listener.