# No event received with onClickListener when ImageView has flag clickable=true

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-imageview

I have `RelativeLayout` with `android:clickable="true"` to change image color from grey to white when button stay pressed (otherwise if `android:clickable="false"` it doesn't work):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/contacts"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_weight="0.2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:clickable="true"   <!-- here clickable = true  -->
    android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_contacts"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/contacts" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:textColor="@drawable/text_color"
    android:text="@string/button_contacts"
    android:textSize="12sp" />    
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

and seems like:

[image]

My `contacts` Selector seems:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/contacts_over" />
<item android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/contacts_selected" />
<item
     android:drawable="@drawable/contacts_default" />
</selector>
```

As you can see I have 3 images: by default, selected and pressed.

According to documentation, after setting `android:clickable="true"` to `ImageView` I stopped to get `onClickListener` event.

```
     contacts = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.contacts);
 contacts.setOnClickListener(this);
```

So I have

- or set `clickable="false"` and "state_pressed" doesn't work
- or set `clickable="true"` and `onClickListener` doesn't work (no event received)

What should I do, any workaround?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set `onClickListener` to your `ImageView` instead of `RelativeLayout`.

And this may interest you too:

[How to pass the onClick event to its parent on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415528/how-to-pass-the-onclick-event-to-its-parent-on-android)

Comment: Excellent, you saved me hours

Answer (score 1):

Work well, if you set `Listner` to your `Imageview` instead `Layout`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ImageButton widget instead of ImageView.

Comment: Can't use it Because Button name has been provided separately.