# Why my RelativeLayout doesn't use selector?

Tags: android, android-selector

I have a RelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/animated_bg">
```

and I've defined a selector

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="@color/ripple_color">
<item>
    <selector>
        <item android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@color/grey_1" />

        <item android:state_focused="true"
            android:drawable="@color/grey_1" />

        <item android:drawable="@color/white" />
    </selector>
</item>
```

but when I press the layout it doesn't change color.

Anyone could notice why this is happening?

**Update**

Here is full xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/animated_bg">

    <RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout>

            <ImageView />

            <LinearLayout>

                <TextView />

                <TextView />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout >

            <LinearLayout >

                <RelativeLayout >

                    <ImageView />

                    <TextView />

                    <TextView />

                    <TextView />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout >

                    <ImageView />

                    <TextView />

                    <TextView />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout >

                <RelativeLayout >

                    <TextView />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Seems to be generally suggested to use the build in selectors unless you want custom colors. Would highly recommend replacing `@drawable/animated_bg` with `?attr/selectableItemBackground`

Answer (score 2):

I have tested your layout with its selector. It works well. However, I do not know if you have any other views/layouts inside your relative layout? If the `RelativeLayout` has child views. These views may consume your event `press` that will result the background does not change its color. In my testing, I do not have any child view inside my relative layout. Could you post your entire layout file?

UPDATE:
If your child views do not need to handle the click event you can set `android:clickable="false"` so the click event will be passed to your parent relative layout. If it is not the case, then this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415528/how-to-pass-the-onclick-event-to-its-parent-on-android) may help you.

Comment: I've added the full layout structure

Comment: Thanks. Settings child view clickable=false and parent clickable=true solved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

In your xml selector color for android:state_pressed android:state_focused is same: @color/grey_1. Try to give different color for both.

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="@color/ripple_color">
<item>
    <selector>
        <item android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@color/grey_1" />

        <item android:state_focused="true"
            android:drawable="@color/grey_1" />

        <item android:drawable="@color/white" />
    </selector>
</item>
```