# How to handle OnLongClickListener in both child and parent

Tags: android, event-handling

I have a probelm when registering a `View.OnLongClickListener` callback to both parent `ViewGroup` and child `View`.

After the child `View` callback has been called, it does not let the event to propagate down to the parent `ViewGroup`, in either `true` or `false` return cases inside the callback `onLongClick(View v)` method.

It is important to note that the parent `ViewGroup` is not a custom `View`.

How can both parent `ViewGroup` and child `View` `View.OnLongClickListener` callbacks be called when long clicking on the child `View`?

Comment: Relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415528/how-to-pass-the-onclick-event-to-its-parent-on-android

Comment: @IsaacPayne `Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` does not pass a `View` object so I cannot determine which view was clicked. `ViewGroup.onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` also does not pass `View` object and this method only relevant for custom `ViewGroup`.