# how to enable click through toolbar in android?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, toolbar, android-toolbar

I have toolbar with transparent colour and below it ImageView.
There is onClickListener for imageView. But if I click on Toolbar, it catch my click, and doesn't through it even with next line in xml:

```
android:clickable="false"
```

is there any other way to prevent toolbar catch clicks?
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415528/how-to-pass-the-onclick-event-to-its-parent-on-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass the onClick event to its parent on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415528/how-to-pass-the-onclick-event-to-its-parent-on-android)