# How can I trigger click event of LinearLayout when I click on a EditText in it?

Tags: android, event-dispatching

```
<LinearLayout id="ll">
  <TextView id="tv">
  </TextView>
  <EditText id="et">
  </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I click tv,I can trigger click event of ll.

But,when I click et,I can't.

It seems that et consume the click event.

How can solve this strange problem?

Comment: Override onclick method of that editText method and call what ever method you need to call in linear layout inside that method

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415528/how-to-pass-a-views-onclick-event-to-its-parent-on-android this will help for u if u want direct way for it

Comment: @Lucefer  It's too much trouble to do like this.