# How to scroll a RecyclerView below a View without clicking on an item of that RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, ontouchlistener

I have a layout where a RecyclerView occupies the entire screen and a CardView is at the bottom of the screen, over the RecyclerView.

[image]

The CardView is not clickable. I do not want the RecyclerView to receive the clicks that happen on the CardView, but I want to be able to scroll the RecyclerView if the user starts scrolling from the CardView.

Is there any simple way to make it?

Comment: To create the layout, I think you could use FrameLayout: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_frame_layout.htm. Passing click events to parent view is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18959830/1501613

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the comment. That was not the question =/

Comment: "I do not want the RecyclerView to receive the clicks that happen on the CardView", you accomplish that by passing events on to parent. I know you did not ask for onClick but rather motion events, I think the accepted answer in the same SO will point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4420394/1501613