# How do I overlap views and add onclick listeners in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, onclick, onclicklistener, overlapping

I want to create a user-interface in Android studio and also add invisible layouts in the background. I want the background layouts to trigger onclick events whenever a UI component above it is clicked.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/texts"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Clicked"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_margin="25dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:onClick="ButtonOne" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="Overlapping">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18959830/8762338 Let me know if you need further help on this

Comment: @AsthaGarg I want both the views/layouts to be clicked, not one. Is there any way that both of the overlapping views can trigger onclick even?

Comment: Try same approach for all the overlapping layouts.

Comment: And if this doesn't work you can easily get the event on your overlapping views and pass it to parent view method.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Astha Garg. But let me clarify, I want different click events on the UI component click and background layout click.