# Propagating click on Views to parent in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a View (button) that animates that sits in front of an overlay. And I can track this visibility i.e View.getVisibility == VISIBLE, ANIMATING, HIDDEN... What I want is, when the View is animating, I want the clicks on it to go to the parent(the overlay) to do something else. And when it's visible, the clicks should apply to the View itself, to do something. The issue is the clicks go to the View while it's animating and not to the parent. I guess the main question is how to make the View appear as not there when animating, so clicks to the parent, and there then its fully visible.

I tried this

```
if (state == ANIMATING) {
 button.setOnClickListener(null)
}

if (state == SHOWING) {
 button.setOnClickListener(v -> {do something})
}
```

what I got was when animating, the button just swallows the click and does not go to the parent

Comment: `button.setClickable(false)` - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415528/how-to-pass-a-views-onclick-event-to-its-parent-on-android

Answer (score 0):

```
parent.setOnClickListener(v -> {do something else})
button.setOnClickListener(v -> {do something})

if (state == ANIMATING) {
 button.setClickable(false)
 button.setFocusable(false)
}

if (state == SHOWING) {
 button.setClickable(true)
 button.setFocusable(true)
}
```