# Why Can't my ListView get long clicked?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am using a listview layout in a descendant of Activity, the Adapter's getView implementation is as follow, it's longclickable:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(CustomTitleActivity.this);
        tv.setText(title[position]);
        return tv;
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

but when I tried inflate the item's view from a layout file like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/local_songs_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:text="TITLE"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSearchResultTitle"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/artist"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:text="Unknow"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSearchResultSubtitle"
            />      
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/favorite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_favourite"
            android:background="#0000"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:onClick="onToggleStar"/>

        <CheckBox 
        android:id="@+id/select"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:focusable="false"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I could not click/long click them, I already tried to set android:focusable attribute to false.
Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: You want to longclick/click on your textviews?

Comment: Have You tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130875/onclicklistener-on-a-linearlayout (in case if You need whole LinearLayout to be clickable) ?

Comment: @Willie Tsang I whant the whole LinearLayout to be clickable.

Comment: @sandrstar Already tried to setClickable and setLongClickable, did not work.

Comment: Do You receive clicks from inner linearlayouts (if listener is set to them)?

Comment: @sandrstar the parent of those two TextView receive clicks.

Comment: then You can just handle clicks on them or work out the way to make them not consume it (unfortunately I'm not familiar on how to accomplish it)

Comment: Thanks all the same, this could be a temporary workaround.

Comment: not sure if it's workaround, as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135032/does-making-parent-clickable-makes-all-child-element-clickable-as-well it works just as it should to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer it myself.
Because in constructor of ImageButton, it would call setFocusable(true) again, so if you really don't need it to be focused, it's ok to call setFocusable(false) after the ImageButton was constructed. Then the problem solved.