# Button not calling OnClickListener

Tags: android, button

I've just created a `ScrollView` that has a `LinearLayout` inside. This `LinearLayout` has a button on the top, and there is nothing I can do. The button's onClickListener is never called.

I want to detect when a user presses the `LinearLayout` and when presses the Button.

Here is my code:

```
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    scrollView.addView(layout);
    layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            layoutClick(v);
        }
    });

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams headerParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,getDpFromPixel(50));

    //bottone per l'header
    Button headerButton = new Button(this);
    headerButton.setId(findId());
    headerButton.setLayoutParams(headerParam);
    //headerButton.setBackground(getResources().getColor(R.color.button_backgroud));
    //headerButton.setBackground(getResources().getColor(R.color.button_backgroud));
    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.color.button_backgroud);
    headerButton.setBackground(d);
    headerButton.setText(title);
    headerButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    headerButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    headerButton.setPadding(70, 0, 0, 0);
    headerButton.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_START);
    headerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buttonPressed(v);
            System.out.println("button pressed!!");
        }
    });
    layout.addView(headerButton);
```

The "layoutClick" function is working, the headerButton is never calling the "buttonPressed" function or printing to console..

Comment: There is no need, the XML is empty (there is only the parent LinearLayout), everithing is created by code.

Comment: okay, where did you add the `headerButton`?

Comment: Did you try using the `.setClickable();` method?

Comment: @Elltz i just added it the the layout just one line after the pasted code, i edited the question.

Comment: See following post [Does making parent click-able make all child element clickable as well?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135032/does-making-parent-clickable-make-all-child-element-clickable-as-well)probably you understand why not working

Comment: No, in that post they are saying: "A clickEvent will be delivered to the lowest child element in the layout hierarchy. If this element does not have an onClick behaviour it will pass the event up to its parent until the event gets handled." So my code should work..

Comment: where is findId() method

Comment: it returns a valid id that isn't in use:
    `public int findId(){
        View v = findViewById(id);
        while (v != null){
            v = findViewById(++id);
        }
        return id++;
    }`

Comment: am sorry, but when you click on it, does the `onClick` of the `LinearLayout` trigger? if it does then you are not clicking the button, if it doesn't then the button fires it but stops on the way probably in `buttonPressed(v);`  method

Comment: Use XML for layouts. Creating GUI in the way you are doing is really messy.

Answer (score 0):

Try making focusable the button

```
headerButton.setFocusable(true);
headerButton.setClickable(true);
```

Comment: A button does not request focus, and it only fires onclick event, so why really add or need that.

Comment: I tried, nothing changed. And why i need to specify the button's clickable property? Default is false?